# import magic throws exception

Tags: python, exception, import

So I used pip to download filemagic:

```
E:\cuckoo-current\cuckoo>c:\Python27\Scripts\pip.exe install filemagic
Downloading/unpacking filemagic
  Downloading filemagic-1.6.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\vaclav~1.vas\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_vaclav.vasenka\filemagic\setup.py) egg_info for package filemagic

Installing collected packages: filemagic
  Running setup.py install for filemagic

Successfully installed filemagic
Cleaning up...
```

I've created test.py with content:

```
import magic
print "test"
```

And when I run the file import throws exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\sand\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import magic
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magic\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from magic.identify import Magic, MagicError
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magic\identify.py", line 16, in <module>
    from magic import api
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\magic\api.py", line 22, in <module>
    raise ImportError('Unable to find magic library')
ImportError: Unable to find magic library
```

Is the filemagic corrupted ? Is this module even working ?

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/aliles/filemagic/blob/master/magic/api.py) why that error is raised - `ctypes.util.find_library('magic') or ctypes.util.find_library('magic1')` evidently evaluates `False`-y.

Comment: Sorry I have very little experiences in python. I don't really get your point. I'm trying to import magic and inside of magic is another import magic which can't be found ? That really doesn't make sense to me :(

Comment: `filemagic` provides a Python interface to `libmagic`; it is the latter that can't be found, the Python part appears to be working. Did you follow the [installation instructions](http://filemagic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide.html#installation)?

Comment: Yes. I've used 'pip.exe install filemagic' and 'pip.exe install libmagic'. Both executed successfully.

Comment: @Eiq there are 2 python modules, one named ``filemagic`` and one named ``libmagic``, BOTH of which are bindings to the **unix** **c** ``libmagic`` library.  You cannot use them on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [PYPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filemagic/1.6) Description (emphasis mine)

> A Python API for libmagic, the library behind the **Unix** file command

and

> libmagic is the library that commonly supports the file command on
>   **Unix** system, other than Max OSX which has its own implementation. The
>   library handles the loading of database files that describe the magic
>   numbers used to identify various file types, as well as the associated
>   mime types. The library also handles character set detections.

You cannot use this on Windows, as you are attempting.

You can attempt to use the [mimetypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html) module in the standard library (`mimetypes.guess_type` would be what to look at).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem with docker containers with *Alpine Linux image*:

It seems like in Alpine Linux the library search doesn't work, hence it fails to find 'libmagic.so.1' which is required for the working of magic library( dependency filemagic and libmagic).

Workaround:

1. Use Python slim instead of Alpine Linux
2. mime, mimetypes are the other python libraries which can be used (the only downside to these two libraries is, that they find the mime type based on file extension and not file headers.

Comment: I faced the same issue on Alpine linux. So I made a fix for it which you can find here https://github.com/aliles/filemagic/pull/20